# Put appbarLayout on bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

**Question**
Is it possible to put a AppBarLayout on the bottom of your screen?

**Problem**
I'm trying to put a bar on the bottom of my screen that scrolls away when I'm scrolling down and appears when I'm scrolling up. Because the Coordinator layout and appbarlayout helped me to do this in a other activity with a toolbar on top I've wanted to try this also on my buttom bar.

This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <MyNameSpace.Views.ScrollViews_Custom.ScrollView_Base
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_movieDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bar_movieDetail_buttom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/actionbar_gray_transparent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, have you eventually succeed with this? Have you found the solution?

Comment: @AlexBerdnikov, I've never managed to do this. Instead I've used a custom view that moves based on a OnScrollListener from my ScrollView.

Comment: Do you still have that layout around? I'm so desperate to find the solution for a week already, I would really appreciate if you share the piece of code or at least the layout through github gist or somewhere else.

Answer (score -4):

```
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

Comment: Not supported to align bottom

Comment: Obviously you just tried to guess it. And it's wrong.